# Getting access denied when trying to copy & paste files

Tags: permissions

I am new to Ubuntu so please forgive my inexperience.

I am running Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.1 and I am set up as an administrator, I am the only user so I believe therefore I should be a root user.

However, when I try to copy a file from the root `/var/www/html` and paste it in `/var/www/` directory, using any file management software (i.e. File manager, Files, Dolphin, etc.), I get the error message: Access denied. Could not write to.

Why can I not write to these directories?

Could this be because I have the automatic login option turned on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're not the root user. In some Linux distros, you are root by default and have to set up other users (because being root is bad practice for security reasons) yourself. In Ubuntu, the user you create during installation is a user with rights to run all commands using the `sudo` program.

This means you can do pretty much anything you want, but you need to use `sudo` to elevate permissions temporarily when you want to do something that requires root permission, such as writing to system directories of which your user is not the owner. **The `sudo` program allows you to run commands as root**

Therefore, to copy a file to a directory you don't own and that does not have permission for you to write to, you could run (in a terminal, open one with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

```
sudo cp /path/to/file /path/to/destination
```

(To copy a directory, use `cp -r`)

Or to use a graphical browser:

```
sudo -i      # to open a root shell
nautilus     # or caja or dolphin or whatever program you use
```

do your thing, and when done, enter

```
exit
```

in the terminal, to drop privileges.

Comment: How to grant rights to write/remove/change files in the copied folder to the other user (that is not root)? – Found it: `sudo chown path-to-your-folder`

Answer (score 0):

Using *sudo* can solve your problem.

*sudo* allows user to run commands as root.

e.g.

1) sudo cp *path for source file*
*path for destination folder*

2) sudo rm -rf  *path of file or folder*

Comment: How exactly is this is different than the answer given yesterday? What does it add?

Comment: Yup! Seems no change. Haven't read the first answer.

Comment: It's just I saw question and answered. :)

Comment: Sudo doesn’t help when using desktop file editor or the file manager to move file and folders. Changing ownership is not a valid solution either but so far I’ve not found the combination of ownership, group membership and permissions that does work!