# why I can not copying file to usr

Tags: inkscape

I want to install inkscape palette and I want to copy the .gpl file into usr why error message appear?

Comment: are you using sudo? the folder is likely owned by root.

Comment: yes I using sudo

Comment: please post the exact command you are using and the error received. add your reply to the question.

Comment: Error while moving “Material-Design.gpl”.

Comment: Error moving file: Permission denied

Comment: and the command used? permission denied usually means you did not use  `sudo`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting access denied when trying to copy & paste files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883708/getting-access-denied-when-trying-to-copy-paste-files)

Answer (score 1):

This works.

```
 sudo cp test.txt /usr
```

You need to be root to add files to /usr, it will ask you for your root password and, if you are the owner, you can move it.

Comment: is it legal ? to do that

Comment: Of course it is assuming your are the owner.